# ejs not rendering after redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I'm having problems to redirect to another router after a Post. I see a 200 status code for the route I'm trying to navigate in the browser console and the whole page in the response payload. Through logs I see the redirect it's working, but the render is just not working.
I'm able to navigate to get to the page if I write the route manually in the browser, tho.
What am I missing?

I'll show you some code:

*Server settings:*

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 9000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(require('./routes'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(basedir, 'public')));
```

*Routes file:*

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('login');
});

router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/index');
})

router.get('/index', (req, res) => {
    res.render('main-page');
})
```

PD: Yes...I'm totally new in Node.

Comment: are you using `express-ejs-layouts`? are your pages rendered but only redirect that doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

From what you say, it sounds like you are sending *an AJAX request*. This means the response is delivered to your JavaScript code, it's not a navigation. So, essentially the redirect "works", as it redirects *your AJAX request* and returns the redirected page content.

If you were to submit a form via the browser (just using a basic `<form>` element), you would see a navigation.

In order for a navigation to occur after an AJAX request, you should not use `res.redirect` but instead return some JSON with the page you want to redirect to (e.g. `res.send({ redirectTo: '/index' })` - the naming is your choice), and then check for the `redirectTo` parameter in your client-side code when it gets the response and navigate there manually using `location.assign`.

Example:

**Server code:**

```js
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  res.send({ redirectTo: '/index' })
})
```

**Client code:**

```js
const result = await fetch('/login', { method: 'POST' })
const { redirectTo } = await result.json()
if (redirectTo) {
  location.assign(redirectTo)
}
```

Alternatively, if the redirection target is static, you don't need any `redirectTo` value and can instead hardcode the target in the client-side code.

In case you want to allow both a form submit or an AJAX request (maybe you do progressive enhancement and your page is designed to work without JavaScript as well), then you can check the `Accept` header and see if HTML is accepted (`req.accepts("html")`), and if it is, you return a redirect, otherwise you return JSON. Similarly, in case of an error, you could conditionally render an error page or return JSON with an error message that your client-side code knows how to handle.